# One Way Communication Problem in Ubuntu Network

Tags: 16.04, networking, remote-desktop, remmina

I have 5 computers networked via the same switch, all running Ubuntu 16.04. I also have internet access through the switch, which all computers are able to use. Recently, one of the computers can no longer connect to one of the other computers.

For this example I'll say the computers are named **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, and **E**. Computer **A** can't ping, ssh into, or use Remmina to access computer **B**. However, it *can* access computers **C**, **D**, and **E**. Computers **B**, **C**, **D**, and **E** can all access each other and computer **A**.

Edit: Since this question was posted, the situation has changed to where none of the computers can access Computer **B**, however, it can still access all of the other computers.

The errors are:

> Ping: Hangs until I quit
>
> SSH: `ssh: connect to host B port 22: No route to host.`
>
> Remmina: `unable to connect to VNC server.`

The only thing I have done since I was able to connect is install standard updates, so I'm not sure where to start looking to fix such a problem.

Comment: Do you have DHCP server in your network and default gateway? What is the topology of your network?

Comment: I do not have a DHCP server, but I do have a default gateway (my router). My network topology is a star.

Comment: I would suggest looking at your firewalls. one computer may be blocking connections to the other.

Comment: I have ufw on all 5, but the status is inactive.

Comment: Maybe it's an ARP problem. Have you tried to unplug and replug the switch to reset its ARP cache? (It takes some time to erase the cache).

Comment: I took the switch offline, but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Do you have the computer on same subnet as others? E.g. 192.168.1.x?

Comment: Yes, they are all on the same subnet.

Answer (score 0):

The computer that was blocking others was automatically obtaining its IP. While it wasn't a problem before, somehow this became an issue that wouldn't go away.

I changed the IP settings to manual (all other computers are manual), rebooted the computer, and that fixed the issue.